# How do you set the color range for a patch object in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, colors

How do you set the color range for a patch object in matplotlib?

```
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('jet')
```

I'm using this is a loop to iterate over a data frame and color patches according to the value returned. I'd like to set the upper and lower bounds of the colourmap.

```
currentAxis = plt.gca()
currentAxis.add_patch(Circle((xpos, ypos), radius, fill=False, color=cmap(a[alt_plot_column]), lw=4))
```

where a[alt_lot_column] returns a float that is used to color the patch by.

The question is - how to scale this colormap so that the max min values are defined by the ranges of the colormap? e.g. 0-20.
I've tried to set the max and vain attributes, but these don't seem to apply to patch objects.

Answer (score 1):

A colormap takes values between 0 and 1 and maps them to a color. Therefore `cmap(20)` will not work.

You would need to somehow normalize your data. In this case it seems easy,

```
norm = lambda x: x/20.
cmap(norm(a))
```

In the general (linear) case you can use a normalization instance

```
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=20)
cmap(norm(a))
```